# Is it possible to access files on iOS with the various compiler applications?

Tags: c++, ios, iphone

I recently downloaded the "CppCode" app for my iPhone and I was just wondering if it was at all possible to access files, change settings, delete things, make calls, etc.

Let's say I wanted to send a text to a friend - could this be possible within the C++ compiler on the iPhone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really a question for stackoverflow, but the answer is no. Your phone, by default, protects its files from apps. Each app exists in its own "sandbox", and is not allowed to leave it under any circumstances. This is what jailbreaking does, it gives you root access to the rest of your phone's internal directories. Even then, I don't think it would be possible. If you really want to do stuff with that, you're better off making an app. I wouldn't try to program stuff from inside some compiler program on-board the phone..